# .Net Core 3.1 webapi hosted and ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, iis

I have a webapi project created in VS2019 using .net core 3.1
The purpose of the project is testing authentication and authorization.
I am able to use IIS Express to run the project, all the routes work as expected.

However, when I publish the project and try to host it in my local IIS Server, when trying to access an anonymous route, I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

If I run "dotnet TestAPI.dll" in the publish folder, I am able to use the API with https://localhost:5001
Trying to use it from IIS, https://localhost/TestAPI/, I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. This is using "Default Web Site" :80 and :443.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    SetAuthenticationStrategy(services);
    services.AddScoped<IAuthService, PocAuthService>();
}

private void SetAuthenticationStrategy(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

    var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);

    services.AddAuthentication(x =>
    {
        x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(x =>
    {
        x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        x.SaveToken = true;
        x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

What am I missing?

Edit, added result of stdout when poking the api with local IIS
Two things I am not sure about

```
Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/TestApi/Auth/Index
```

Even thought I used https, it is expected?

Not sure what key this is referring to or why the expiration date is so short.

```
Creating key {...} with creation date 2019-12-31 15:41:47Z, activation date 2019-12-31 15:41:47Z, and expiration date 2020-03-30 15:41:47Z
```

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]

      Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]

      Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]

      Creating key {...} with creation date 2019-12-31 15:41:47Z, activation date 2019-12-31 15:41:47Z, and expiration date 2020-03-30 15:41:47Z.

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]

      No XML encryptor configured. Key {...} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Hosting environment: Production

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Content root path: C:\web\testapi

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]

      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/TestApi/Auth/Index  

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]

      Request finished in 8.9062ms 307 

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Application is shutting down...
```

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html#background Common things you might miss.

Comment: I suggest you could firstly edit your web.config and set `stdoutLogEnabled="true"` to true to see what happended when you send the request to the IIS web api.

Comment: I did set the log to true, the file is created, but is empty when sending the request to IIS. When I start the app with the dotnet command it works as expected.